# Is OAuth1 the correct signing process for the Large Scale Matrix API?

Tags: here-api

I am working on the large scale matrix API, and I am confused by the documentation. The "[Create a Signature](https://developer.here.com/documentation/large-matrix/dev_guide/topics/get-started/create-a-signature.html)" documentation says to use OAuth1 to sign the request. However, "[Request a Token](https://developer.here.com/documentation/large-matrix/dev_guide/topics/get-started/request-a-token.html)" uses OAuth2 in the URL at the top of the page. It also appears that other Here services use OAuth2. What is the correct signing method to use?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have an access key and signature, you can request a token using the token REST API. A typical request includes these elements:

https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: OAuth
    oauth_consumer_key="<Access Key>",
    oauth_nonce="<Random string, uniquely generated for each request>",
    oauth_signature="<Signature>",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",
    oauth_timestamp="<Epoch seconds>",
    oauth_version="1.0"
```

OAuth 2 is in Url only , you have to use OAuth 1.0 for the authorization as below-

[image]

follow this for more detailed information.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-postman.html